# creating codeigniter dynamic template

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

i want to put login form in navigation(template) so that it will be shown in all the pages.
and will check username and password in database without going to other pages. if failed, an error will be shown in the nav and if success, the page will be reloaded again with specific costomizations. please tell me how with code and details.

i have these parts in my template:

1. header
2. nav
3. footer
4. and content that will be added in current controller

i wanna do this in each controller:

```
$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('templates/nav');
$this->load->view('related_view');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

but my navigation should contain a login form which will not go to another page by submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to extend the Controller class. So In this case we should make an extended controller (for example MY_Controller) and put the dynamic action (here authentication) in it as a method.

Then we should extend this self-made controller in each of our controllers , so authentication in the template would be simply handled.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this:

```
<?php
$this->load->view('templates/header');

if ($this->user_model->isLoggedIn())
{
    // Logged-in users should see this view
    $this->load->view('templates/nav-registered');
}
else
{
    // Guests should see this
    $this->load->view('templates/nav-guest');
}

$this->load->view('related_view');
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

You'll thank yourself if you override the Loader class to grab your header/footer for you automatically, not having to code this in **EVERY** controller method.  Just a thought..

Comment: my question is where to place login controller and model. in a separate class extending ci_controller and ci_model? if so how to include them in current controller? you know, for example this is my news controller and i load these template views in this controller. in my login form i have action="" so it posts data to current page. so the login controller and model must be accessible in current controller(news controller) in some way to process login checks. thx for answer!

Comment: Why do you want to handle the login at every URI?  Why not have you login form *always* point to the same controller action.  That way you don't have to check needlessly for login post data on every request...

Comment: well i extremely need that. and notice that my question is general and is about dynamic template(here navigation). and login form is just an example . for example i want to show some random news in my navigation or anything which is dynamic and not just static text.($this->load->view() doesn't work). you know dynamic action needs controller and maybe model. my question is how to handle these controllers and models inside the main current controller

Answer (score 0):

use session to check loged user, and put this on the nav view, but first make sure you have session loaded from auload or from your controller

```
if($this->session->userdata('user_loged')){
      //code to put some navigation when use is loged
}else{
    //code to put login form
}
```